# Compatibility of excel add-in 2003 with .net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have created an Excel Add-In for office 2003/2007 in Visual studio 2008 with .net framework 3.5.  I have used dlls of some other project in my excel add-in project.

Due to some reason i have to update dlls in .net framework 4.0.

So i need to create Excel Add-In for office 2003/2007 in Visual studio 2010 with .net framework 4.0.

Will it be compatible for office 2003?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: i just wanted a quick response without wasting time. If any one has any idea, please share to me.

Comment: If you had tried it out, you'd know the answer by now.

Comment: This is created, but not showing in Ribbon. I have added a command  bar. Do you want code to check?

Comment: If you have a specific problem, then ask a specific question.

Comment: can't you give me specific answer or any link from where i can resolve my problem? Try to understand.

Comment: You haven't asked a question! See [ask].

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ddcf190-1b08-4f6b-99ff-3b9de0061bce/vs2010-vs-excel-2003-addin?forum=vsto.

Comment: Kindly go through the link, this is telling that VS 2010 will not support excel add-in 2003

Comment: Thanks a lot to remind me about "How to Ask".